# How to get uploaded file name and size in phonegap

Tags: cordova

All,

I'm trying to get the file name and file type of a photo using PhoneGap/Cordova 2.4 from below code.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality:50, destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, mediaType:navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA});
```

How to get this file name and file type from below callback function and from base64(imageData) data. I unable to get please help me to solve this problem

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do better (as [recommended](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)) to set the destinationType parameter to Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI rather than DATA_URL.

You can then extract the filename from that URI using, for example:

```
var filename = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

When you say file type, I assume you mean JPEG, PNG or similar? If so, the simplest way of doing so would simply be to look at the file extension from the filename:

```
var extension = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
switch (extension.toLowerCase()) {
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg":
    // Do something with JPEGs
    break;
  case "png":
    // Do something with PNGs
    break;
  default:
    // Some other image format...
    break;
}
```

Comment: To ensure no one waste their time trying this.... This no longer works with newer phonegap builds 3.0+ because the returned url does not contain an extension.